# Cannot cast org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer to jakarta. servlet.ServletContainerInitializer

Tags: spring, spring-boot-3

I'm trying to to load a deployable springboot war to my SpringBoot 3 project.
And i'm getting the exception on the title.
On windows machine it's working 100% fine But on MainFrame USS  environment i'm getting this error.

I'm following the article on -> https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-add-war-to-embedded-tomcat

I did exactly as in the link above but with a small changes for SpringBoot 3 , What am i doing wrong ? .

Any help please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.